# How to extract URL's with specific text?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract URL's that contain specific line of the URL such as **/example/example1/newexample/**

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/example/example1/newexample/testing.aspx">Testing</a>
```

My current code returns all hyperlinks on the page. How do i only extract those links with just **/example/example1/newexample/**

```
Sub GetAllLinks()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    url_name = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub
    IE.navigate (url_name)

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set AllHyperlinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
    Sheet1.ListBox1.Clear

    For Each Hyperlink In AllHyperlinks
        Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem (Hyperlink)
    Next

    IE.Quit
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below

```
For Each Hyperlink In AllHyperlinks
    If InStr(1, Hyperlink, "/example/example1/newexample/", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem (Hyperlink)
    End If
Next
```

Also, you need to change

`Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` to `Loop Until IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Sub GetAllLinks(byval filter as string)
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim url_name As String
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  url_name = Sheet1.Range("B2")
  If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub
  IE.navigate (url_name)
  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Set AllHyperlinks = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
  Sheet1.ListBox1.Clear
  For Each Hyperlink In AllHyperlinks
    If InStr(Hyperlink.href, filter) > 0 Then
      Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem (Hyperlink)
    end if
  Next
  IE.Quit
  MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

filter ist your string. So use it like this:

```
call GetAllLinks("/example/example1/newexample/")
```

btw it would be a good idea to use

```
Option Explicit
```

and define your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to avoid initial loop and target with CSS selector and then loop the returned nodeList

```
Dim aNodeList As Object,  i As Long
Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelector("a[href^='/example/example1/newexample/']")

For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length-1
   Debug.print aNodeList.item(i).getAttribute("href")
Next i
```

The `^` means starts with so `a[href^='/example/example1/newexample/']` is looking for elements with `a` tag containing attribute `href` starting with `'/example/example1/newexample/'`

Here is the CSS selector in action on your html sample:

[image: CSS query]